# exclude relations based on relation parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a neo4j cypher traversal problem.

setup:
I have a query which starts at node "a" and gives me all the paths with the relation "FOO". All these "FOO" relations have a parameter "BAR". The parameter "BAR" can have 2 (or more) values "1" and "2".  Now I want to exclude all paths containing one or more FOO.BAR="2" relation.

The query: START a=node(x)  MATCH a-[rh:FOO*]->b RETURN rh; 
rh gives me all possible paths, but I don't know how to add criteria regarding a relationship.

I have a scenario created in the console (http://console.neo4j.org/?id=219eub)

```
    create 
    (a  {name:"A"}),
    (b {name:"B"}),
    (c  {name:"C"}),
    (d  {name:"D"}),
    b-[:FOO{BAR:'1'}]->a,
    d-[:FOO{BAR:'1'}]->a,
    c-[:FOO{BAR:'2'}]->b,
    d-[:FOO{BAR:'1'}]->c

    START n=node(4) 
    MATCH n-[rh:FOO*]-b 
    RETURN rh;
```

This gives me
Query Results

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | n.name | rh                                                      | b.name |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | "D"    | [:FOO[2] {BAR:"1"}]                                     | "A"    |
    | "D"    | [:FOO[3] {BAR:"1"}]                                     | "C"    |
    | "D"    | [:FOO[3] {BAR:"1"},:FOO[1] {BAR:"2"}]                   | "B"    |
    | "D"    | [:FOO[3] {BAR:"1"},:FOO[1] {BAR:"2"},:FOO[0] {BAR:"1"}] | "A"    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but I only want

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | n.name | rh                                                      | b.name |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | "D"    | [:FOO[2] {BAR:"1"}]                                     | "A"    |
    | "D"    | [:FOO[3] {BAR:"1"}]                                     | "C"    |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rh` is a collection you can apply [predicate functions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-function.html#_predicates):

```
START n=node(4) 
MATCH n-[rh:FOO*]->b 
WHERE not any(r in rh where r.BAR="2") 
RETURN rh;
```

Comment: solved, pff, I feel such a noob. When you see the sollution it's sooo deuh ;-) I must admit that predicate functions and using/nesting WHERE's is something to get used to (which I'm not). Thanks Stefan, you made my day.

Comment: The big difference is that `rh` is a collection in variable length paths vs a single relationship for a normal match.

Comment: what's the difference between filtering with `WHERE rh.BAR=1` instead of the above filter?

Comment: since `rh` is a collection (FOO* is variable length!) you can't access a property on that. Therefore the collection functions need to be used.